How to interpret the RSan memory?
From the man page of top, I found RSan is part of RES (resident memory) as follows.
                              Private | Shared
                                 1           |          2
            Anonymous  . stack               |
                       . malloc()            |
                       . brk()/sbrk()        | . POSIX shm*
                       . mmap(PRIVATE, ANON) | . mmap(SHARED, ANON)
                      -----------------------+----------------------
                       . mmap(PRIVATE, fd)   | . mmap(SHARED, fd)
          File-backed  . pgms/shared libs    |
                                 3           |          4

---

          RES  - anything occupying physical memory which, beginning with
                 Linux-4.5, is the sum of the following three fields:
                 RSan - quadrant 1 pages, which include any
                        former quadrant 3 pages if modified
                 RSfd - quadrant 3 and quadrant 4 pages
                 RSsh - quadrant 2 pages

RSan should mean anonymous RES. But we have the following line from the statement above:

include any former quadrant 3 pages if modified

There is a post Memory - Part 2: Understanding Process memory:

since private file-backed pages that are modified don’t get synced back to disk, they are not file-backed anymore

However, the post does not explain in details. Do you know how modified quadrant 3 pages are converted to RSan?

I try to understand this issue.
The statement below does not mean quadrant 3 pages are converted to quadrant 1 type. The page type is not changed, but the underlying kernel-level share is removed.
RSan - quadrant 1 pages, which include any
       former quadrant 3 pages if modified

Quadrant 3 pages, from the viewpoint of process, are private, but might be shared by other processes due to kernel-level optimization.
Take the .text section of a program, for example, multiple processes of the same program have the same .text section in their virtual memory space. In order to use less RAM, the kernel maps those virtual pages to the same RAM frames. Therefore, from the viewpoint of kernel, those pages are shared.
If a process intends to write those pages, the kernel will allocate new RAM frames. Consequently, that process would not share RAM frames with the rest process any more.
